# Merging dataframes results in NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes that both have a timestamp, I want to join them on that timestamp.

When I merge the two, the column 'Occupants' results in all NaN values.

Anyone have an idea why this is going on?

Here's the two dataframes:

[weather_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljy3t.png)

[occupants_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIAA9.png)

Using `pd.merge(weather_log_short, Occupancy_short, on='realtime', how='left')` gives me this:

[weather_and_occupants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wFFY.png)

PS. Sorry i don't know how to make tables in the editor.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the dataframes on the question so that everyone can copy that - rather than the images?

Comment: It looks like `'realtime'` is a string in weather_log, but a `datetime` in occupants. Convert both with `pd.to_datetime` then merge.

Comment: @ALollz you're right, I converted to datetime and it works! Thank you

Comment: @harvpan sorry I'm working in Jupyter Notebooks. Copying/Pasting the dataframes just spits out an unreadable table, I know i'm missing something...